# python regular expression - re.findall() in list

Tags: regex, python-2.7

This is my list:

```
lista=[u'REG_S_3_UMTS_0_0 (RNC)', u'REG_S_3_UMTS_0_1 (RNC)', u'REG_S_3_UMTS_0_2 (RNC)', u'REG_S_2_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_2_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_2_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_IPAC_SABP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_IPAC_SABP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_IPAC_SABP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_CLNS_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_CLNS_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_CLNS_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_RFC1_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_RFC1_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_RFC1_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_SIEM_BSCI_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_SIEM_BSCI_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_SIEM_BSCI_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'Pool ID: 200']
```

And that's my function:

```
def Filter_List(lista):

     string = ''.join(lista)
     match = re.findall(r"\(([A-Z]+)\)|Pool ID", string)
     return match
```

As a result I get:

```
[u'RNC', u'RNC', u'RNC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'BSC', u'']
```

But the last element (it should be: Pool ID) doesn't display.There's only: u'' . Does anyone know how should I change my expression? Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that [**`re.findall`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns (list of) tuples if a regex pattern has capture groups defined. Remove it:

```
import re
lista=[u'REG_S_3_UMTS_0_0 (RNC)', u'REG_S_3_UMTS_0_1 (RNC)', u'REG_S_3_UMTS_0_2 (RNC)', u'REG_S_2_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_2_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_2_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_IPAC_SABP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_IPAC_SABP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_IPAC_SABP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_CLNS_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_CLNS_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_CLNS_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_RFC1_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_RFC1_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NOKI_RFC1_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_SIEM_BSCI_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_SIEM_BSCI_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_3_GSM_SIEM_BSCI_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_ERIC_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUAP_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_HUA_CBSM_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_0 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_1 (BSC)', u'REG_S_GSM_NORT_CBSP_bsc_0_2 (BSC)', u'Pool ID: 200']
string = ''.join(lista)
match = re.findall(r"\([A-Z]+\)|Pool ID", string)
print(match)
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/3lrsnj) returning

`[u'(RNC)', u'(RNC)', u'(RNC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'(BSC)', u'Pool ID']`